# Is there a function to cast string tokenizer to array

Tags: java, string, casting, stringtokenizer

I am working over an hour to find a way to explode a string into a string array.

This method have failed for me:

```
lineFields = str.split("|");
System.out.print(lineFields.length);
```

because it gives back an array of equal length to the string it self.

Then I read here that string tokenizer can explode a string, but unfortunately I cannot find a way to access the element randomly like `lineFields[1]`.

I come from php and doing the simpliest things here looks so unusual, and of course I have searched the relative post on this forum, but still nothing close to my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't try to use StringTokenizer where `split(...)` should be used.
- Just because your attempt to use split(...) isn't working doesn't mean that it's the wrong tool for the job.
- You're using split wrong. Don't forget to escape your pipe, `|` String: `"\\|"`

Comment: Thank you very, much! how do I escape it, isn't double quote enough?

Comment: It worked right away, I was so sceptical to ask, being afraid of down voting. Thank you very much again!

Comment: +1. But I think an explanation is needed on why the pipe must be escaped this way. String.split takes a regex as argument. And the pipe is a logical operator in the regex syntax. To be treated as a literal pipe character, it must be escaped with a backslash. Since the backslash must itself be escaped with another backslash in a String literal, we end up with `\\|`

Comment: @JBNizet: thanks for your lucid explanation! Sorry for not adding something like it in my initial post.